# Covering index for a column on the right side of equals

Tags: mysql, sql

Please give me advice on what covering index should be created for the following query:

```
SELECT id
  FROM user
 WHERE email_address = '...' AND
       hashed_password = SHA2(CONCAT(salt, '...'), 256))
```

Because salt is also a column in the table, I'm unsure which of these is correct:

```
INDEX (email_address, hashed_password, id)

INDEX (email_address, hashed_password, salt, id)
```

Then again, since email address returns one row, putting hashed_password in the index seems redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, its a bit redundant.

As long as one of the indexes begins with `email` that is fine. You'll probably want a unique key on `email` alone to prevent duplicate email addresses being entered.

An innodb (and probably other engines) index will implicitly end in its primary key (assumed to be `id`) so there's never a need to explicitly add it.

While adding `hashed_password`, `salt` to the index will improve performance allowing the entire query to be served by the index, it does increase the index size slightly and I'm not sure you'll gain much from it, particularly as this just looks like a login.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule for index selection, you should look at all the queries that you will be running against that table and select an index using the smallest number of columns common to all of those queries.

A common choice *might* be the primary key (PK). In the case of a table of users, the PK is probably a good choice.

For example, if there is another use of the "user" table that, say, just returns the user's details (e.g. department, phone number, full name etc) that is used by a system administrator, would the system administrator have that user's password?

Answer, probably not. So I would be inclined in this case to just use the email_address - assuming that this is equivalent to the user ID.

Having said, that, I note that you are selecting "id" in your query. What is the id column? Is that the real user ID? i.e. is that the value they would normally enter when logging in / changing password? If so, then "id" is probably a better candidate for the index.

FWIW, as written, if the user gets the password (or the email_addr) wrong, then the query will return no records. If they get it right, assuming email_addr is unique in the table, then it will return one record. Is that what you were expecting?